# Updating jquery associative array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update values of an array but I am getting null instead. Here is how I populate the array:

```
   var id_status = []; id_status.push({ id:1, status: "true" });
```

So basically I end creating a JSON object with this array but how do I update individual values by looping through the array? Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id"); id_status[id] = "false";
```

I want to be able to access the item in the array and update its' status after getting the row id.

Comment: There are no arrays in jQuery, and in javascript there are no associative arrays ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find object by id in array of javascript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: It seems that you confuse ids and indexes. Firstly, read the question above to find the object with the corresponding id, then update the object like this : `foundObject.status = false`.

Comment: This answer is fine : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7364184/1636522. `findById(id_status, id).status = false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id_status = {};  // start with an objects

id_status['1'] = {status: true }; // use keys, and set values

var id = this.id;  // assuming it returns 1

id_status[id].status = false; // access with the key
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will either update an existing status or add a new object with the appropriate status and id.

```
var id_status = []; 
id_status.push({ id:1, status: true }); //using actual boolean here
setStatus(1, false);
setStatus(2, true);

//print for testing in Firefox
for(var x = 0; x < id_status.length; x++){
    console.log(id_status[x]);
} 

function setStatus(id, status){
    //[].filter only supported in modern browsers may need to shim for ie < 9
    var matches = id_status.filter(function(e){
       return e.id == id;
    });
    if(matches.length){
        for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
           matches[i].status = status; //setting the status property on the object
        } 
    }else{
        id_status.push({id:id, status:status});
    }
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rE939/

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` is going to be unique, make `id_status` an object like this

```
var id_status = {};
id_status[1] = "true";   //Boolean value in String?!?
```

Access it with the `id` directly to get the status

```
console.log(id_status[1]);
```

Since, objects are like hashtable, accessing the elements will be faster.